# Is it possible to put spaces instead of numbers in a matrix?

Tags: c

I want to put spaces instead of 3's and create a plus sign from 1's. Like peg solitaire board. How can I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    int board[7][7]={{3,3,1,1,1,3,3},{3,3,1,1,1,3,3},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{3,3,1,1,1,3,3},{3,3,1,1,1,3,3}};
    int i,j;

    for ( i=0;i<7; i++)
    {
        for ( j=0; j<7; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d ",board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not directly use `'+'` and `' '` instead of the numbers and print them using `%c`?

Comment: @th33lf Because `'+'` and `' '` are actually `int` values in C.  So it's **impossible** to put those values into an `int` variable as characters and know they're actually those `char` values. What happens if the number is 32? And ASCII is used for `char` encoding?  And you can't really do it C++, either, even though character literals are actual `char` values in C++, as they get converted to `int` values when they're assigned to an `int` variable.  Bottom line is, the values in an `int` are just bits - and those bits represent an `int`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Maybe it's my ignorance about peg-solitaire, but what I meant is to use chars instead of ints everywhere.

Comment: @AndrewHenle emm what??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just write the Spaces and Pluses in your Array (if the Array is not changing) ofc then you need to change the array type, or use my Code here:

I used a `switch case` so you could even define more Numbers with different outputs:)

```
int main()
{ 
    int board[7][7]={{3,3,1,1,1,3,3},{3,3,1,1,1,3,3},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{3,3,1,1,1,3,3},{3,3,1,1,1,3,3}};
    int i,j,number;

    for ( i=0;i<7; i++)
    {   for ( j=0; j<7; j++)
        {
           number = board[i][j];
           switch(number){
               case 1: printf("+"); break;
               case 3: printf(" "); break;
               default : printf("%d", board[i][j]); break;
           }
        }
    printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Output:

```
  +++  
  +++  
+++++++
+++0+++
+++++++
  +++  
  +++
```

I hope thats what you wanted!

Answer (score 3):

On `int board[][]` it is not possible to assign '+' or '' inplace of 3 or 1 because your defined 2-D array is of type int and you want to replace it with char. Still if you perform the assignment like `board[3][3]= '+'` it will store ascii value of '+'.

So either you have to create new 2-D array of type char and replace value when conditions are met.

**OR**

You just have to iterate and inplace of 3 and 1 just print '+' and '' when conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put values of different data types in a matrix in C. All the values should be of the same data type. So instead of using a matrix I am using loops to print the pattern that you want. Also I am assuming that the pattern you want is of size 7. If you want a more generic answer then please add a couple of more examples of how the pattern would look for different sizes. Please let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.

```
void printTopAndBottom(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<2;j++){
            printf("1 ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
void printFinalPattern(){
    printTopAndBottom();
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<7;j++){
            if(i==1 && j==3){
                printf("0 ");
            }
            else{
                printf("1 ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printTopAndBottom();
 }
 int main(){
     printFinalPattern();
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is checking the value insite the loop, then printing proper character, like below:

```
int main()
{ 
    int board[7][7]={{3,3,1,1,1,3,3},{3,3,1,1,1,3,3},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{3,3,1,1,1,3,3},{3,3,1,1,1,3,3}};
    int i,j;

    for ( i=0;i<7; i++)
    {   
        for ( j=0; j<7; j++)
        {
            switch (board[i][j])
            {
                case 0:
                    printf(" 0 "); // is that expected?
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf(" + ");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf("   ");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to use chars instead of ints and use `%c` to print them, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    char board[7][7]={{' ',' ','+','+','+',' ',' '},{' ',' ','+','+','+',' ',' '},{'+','+','+','+','+','+','+'},{'+','+','+','0','+','+','+'},{'+','+','+','+','+','+','+'},{' ',' ','+','+','+',' ',' '},{' ',' ','+','+','+',' ',' '}};
    int i,j;

    for ( i=0;i<7; i++)
    {   for ( j=0; j<7; j++)
        {
          printf(" %c ",board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
       +  +  +
       +  +  +
 +  +  +  +  +  +  +
 +  +  +  0  +  +  +
 +  +  +  +  +  +  +
       +  +  +
       +  +  +
```

Comment: You can use `int`s as well, nothing will break if you just change the `char board[7][7]` to `int board[7][7]`.